# Triple boot on Macbook pro: Mac (Mountain Lion), Windows 7, Fedora 17

Tags: macos, fedora, boot-camp

I'm now having windows 7 dual booted with Mac OSx (Mountain Lion), I want to install fedora 17 as well.

All the search results I found tells me that I can make the triple boot but the HDD must be single partition at first.

Is there a way to make another partition for fedora the same I did for windows 7 without having to reformat the HDD to 3 partitions from the beginning? or install fedora from windows on the boot camp?

also I have rEFIT installed, tell me if It can be useful in the process.

P.S. I don't want to use VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Given the `rEFIt` documentation, it would appear that you should be able to use it to add Fedora 17 to your Mac with or without `rEFIt`. It is easier to triple boot when you have one starter partition to put the boot loader on and your OSs on the other three, but the Mac hardware should be able to let you switch boot disk easily enough and `rEFIt` should also give you an easy way to do it as well. Just follow their documentation.